# Best Java design pattern to handle console commands

Tags: java, design-patterns, console

I'm trying to create a console to handle console commands from a `string`.

At the moment I'm using if statements to check for each command like this:

```
if (command.contains("new train")) {
    command = command.replace("new train ", "");
    Train t = new Train();
    t.setCode(command);
    ServiceProvider.getTrainService().saveOrUpdate(t);
    responeHandler("train " + command + " created");
}
```

But this isn't the best solution in my opinion.

I'm wondering whether there is already a good design pattern for problems like this?

I have looked at the `builder` and `factory` patterns but can't really decide if they are the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Command` and `Factory` pattern maybe?

```
interface Command {
    void execute();
}

interface CommandFactory {
    boolean canCreate(String input);
    Command fromInput(String input); // or return Optional so it can be a FunctionalInterface
}

class TrainCommand implements Command {
    String train;
    public TrainCommand(String t) {  train = t; }
    public void execute() {
        ServiceProvider.getTrainService().saveOrUpdate(t);
    }
}

class TrainCommandFactory {
    public boolean canCreate(String t) {
        return t.contains("new train ");
    }
    public Command fromString(String c) {
        return new TrainCommand(c.replace("new train ", ""));
    }
}
```

And a `Singleton` `Composite` CommandFactory that iterates all known Command Factories:

```
class CommandFactories implements CommandFactory {
    private static final CommandFactories INSTANCE;
    private List<CommandFactory> delegates = Arrays.asList(
        new TrainCommandFactory()
        // others
    };
    public boolean canCreate(String t) {
        return delegates.stream()
            .filter(cf -> cf.canCreate(t))
            .findAny().isPresent();
    }
    public Command fromString(String c) {
        return delegates.stream()
            .filter(cf -> cf.canCreate(t))
            .findAny()
            .map(CommandFactory::fromString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great but does my code really need to create a new command instance from a TrainCommandFactory everytime it gets called? Also what do you exactly mean with `Singleton` `Composite`? Composite is like a tree of objects if I'm right? And a singleton can only hold 1 instance. How do you want me to connect those 2?

Comment: Edited my answer for the Composite Singleton Factory. If you don't want to create a command instance every time, you can make the `TrainCommand` singleton and just have the factory return it every time it its `fromString`is  called. But then you'd need to change `execute` to accept the String argument.

Comment: Thanks alot I used a combination of your and Martin Frank his answer!

Answer (score 1):

A `Map<String, Consumer<String>>` could do the job to associate commands to actions.
It is not the GOF factory and command DP.
But these are fair and simple implementations of factory and command pattern.
So you should consider it too.

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> actionsByCommand = new HashMap<>();

actionsByCommand.put("new train", command->{
     command = command.replace("new train ", "");
        Train t = new Train();
        t.setCode(command);
        ServiceProvider.getTrainService().saveOrUpdate(t);
        responeHandler("train " + command + " created");
});

actionsByCommand.put("delete train", command->{
     command = command.replace("delete train ", "");
     ...
});

// and so for...
```

You could also create a special action for invalid commands that you don't need to put in the map :

```
Consumer<String> invalidCommandAction = (command-> System.out.println("Invalid command. Here are the accepted commands..."));
```

To improve the testability and the maintainability of action classes,  you could 
move them into distinct classes.

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> actionsByCommand = new HashMap<>();

actionsByCommand.put("new train", new NewTrainCommand());
actionsByCommand.put("delete train", new DeleteTrainCommand());
```

With `NewTrainAction` defined as :

```
public class NewTrainAction implements Consumer<String>{

    public void accept(String command){
         command = command.replace("new train ", "");
         Train t = new Train();
         t.setCode(command);
         ServiceProvider.getTrainService().saveOrUpdate(t);
            responeHandler("train " + command + " created");
   }

}
```

And other Actions defined in the same way.

Then you can use them in this way :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String command = scanner.nextLine();
    Consumer<String> action = actionsByCommand.getOrDefault(command, invalidCommandAction);
    action.accept(command);
}
```

Comment: Is there a pattern you can refer to with this answer? I'm trying to split my commands into classes instead of using the same class with a huge function.

Comment: I updated to answer to your requirements and your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your commands in an array and when the user enters a command, you could find the item having the given index. The index would be meaningful and usable in a switch-case and if the item is not found, you could give a meaningful response.

Also, you could do this in a case-insensitive manner of having the keys in the array all lower characters and turning the command key to lower before the search:

```
protected String[] supportedCommands = {"first", "second", "third"};
public static int findCommand(String command) {
    for (var i = 0; i < supportedCommands.length; i++) {
        if (command.equals(supportedCommands[i])) return i;
    }
    return -1; //Not found
}

public static void handleCommand(String command) {
    int c = findCommand(command.toLowerCase());
    switch (c) {
        case 1: {/*...*/} break;
        default: {/*Handle Undefined command*/}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really trying to split my commands into classes with a good pattern. Looking at your answer I would still be writing all my code in the same class. This way my switch case and array just gets bigger and bigger over time? (When adding new commands)

Comment: @klokklok nothing forces you to keep the commands in the very same class with the engine. You can separate it as you like or need to.

Comment: You are right it doesn't. But my problem was that I had no idea how to split those classes up the right way. I wanted to avoid putting everything under each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think using defined commands is the proper way. An important issue for a command would be to be identified (`matches`) by the `commandString` and to be executed (`execute`). Once you have created custom `Command`  you can register them in a List and execute them.

```
interface Command{
    boolean matches(String commandString);
    boolean execute(String commandString);
}
```

an Example implementation would be

```
CreateTrainCommand implements Command{

    private final CMDSTRING = "new train";

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CommandString cmdStr){
        if(cmdStr != null && cmdStr.toLowerCase.startsWith(CMDSTRING)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CommandString cmdStr){
         if(cmdStr != null){
             String train = cmdString.toLowerCase.replace(CMDSTRING, "").trim();

             //here comes your command execution
             Train t = new Train();
             ...
         }
        return true;//execution succesful
    }
}
```

if you want to use these command store all commands into a List (or any other collection) and check if your command matches your input

```
List<Command> cmds = ...
cmds.add(new CreateTrainCommand()); //add all commands that were implemented 
//or only some commands if the user has restricted access
```

here is how you apply the commands

```
String commandString = ... //from Scanner or where else
for(Command cmd: cmds){ //use streams if you're java 8
    if (cmd.matches(commandString)){
        boolean wasSuccesful = cmd.execute(commandString);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Spring world you can use

You could consider to implement

```
org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
```

Each command could be executed in its own CommandLineRunne instance.

Use

```
org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource
```

to parse your command line